# Do functions $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with these properties exist?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, permutations, existence-theorems

Basically, I am trying to determine how exactly and in which ways everywhere discontinuous bijections $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ "behave when they are unusual".

More precisely, I am trying to somehow characterize those "unusual" everywhere discontinuous bijections.

And I was thinking about does at least one function that has all these six properties exist:

1) $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$

2) $f$ is everywhere discontinuous

3) $f$ is a bijection

4) $f(\mathbb Q) \cap \mathbb Q=\emptyset$

5) $f(\mathbb Q)$ is everywhere dense in $\mathbb I$

Here, $\mathbb I$ is the set of all irrational numbers and the meaning of 5) is the following:

For every $i \in \mathbb I$ and every real $\epsilon>0$ there exists at least one sequence $r_n(i)$ such that $r_n(i) \in \mathbb Q$ for every $n \in \mathbb N$ and $f(\{r_n(i): n \in \mathbb N\}) \subset (i-\epsilon,i+\epsilon)$

And, finally:

6) If $i,j \in \mathbb I$ and $i \neq j$ then $\{r_n(i): n \in \mathbb N\} \cap \{r_n(j): n \in \mathbb N\}=\emptyset$

Comment: $r_1(i) \in \mathbb{Q}$ for all $i \in \mathbb{I}$, and $\mathbb{I}$ is uncountable so 6 cannot hold by the pigeonhole principle, if I understand the quantification

Comment: As to the first **5** properties you may just define for all $q\in\mathbb{Q}$, $f(q)=q+\sqrt{2}$, $f(q+\sqrt{2})=q$, and $f(x)=x$ otherwise.

Comment: @VilleSalo I understand what you mean by that, but I do not know now how to rigorously prove that there is not enough rationals in a way that 5) and 6) obstruct existence of such functions.

Comment: No, not really that "there is not enough" of them, but that they cannot be distributed in such a way for 5) and 6) to hold simultaneously.

Comment: For each $i \in \mathbb{I}$, $r_1(i)$ is a rational number. Since $\{r_n(i) : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $\{r_n(j) : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ are disjoint for $i,j \in \mathbb{I}$, $i \neq j$, in particular $r_1(i) \neq r_1(j)$. This means $r_1 : \mathbb{I} \to \mathbb{Q}$ is injective. But indeed, maybe I misunderstand the quantification. Also, I think you'd get better answers for this question on math.stackexchange.

Comment: You could replace 6) with a condition requiring that the sequences are *almost disjoint*, meaning that any two of them have finite intersection (rather than empty intersection, which, as pointed out, is impossible-to-satisfy). However, once you have that the image of the rationals is dense in $\mathbb I$, this new requirement holds automatically.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I was thinking about that, but did not make an edit (yet). Also, other conditions other than *almost-disjointness* but similar to it can be formulated. I discovered at least one slightly interesting condition and I think that others other than that one can be discovered, but also similar to it.